# scope of autorelease pool

Tags: objective-c

Does NSAutoreleasePool also covers variables in all the called methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the only place where `-isNotExpired` is called, the auto release pool you've set up will contain objects autoreleased in `-isNotExpired` (including startDate).

Note that in a normal Cocoa application, `NSApplicationMain()` called in `main()` in main.m will create an autorelease pool for you, so this code wouldn't leak anyway. You generally only create your own autorelease pool in cases where you'll be generating lots of temporary objects with a short useful life (in a loop for instance) and want to keep your high water memory usage down.

Comment: Oh, sure that's another reason to create your own autorelease pool. Still, I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: The `continue` statement is meaningless, as written.... but the `...`s imply there might be a loop around it.

Comment: Don't forget that another reason to create an autoreleasepool is `__attribute__((constructor))`!